# Recyclerview scroll to a specific position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` of different categories. Each category has its own products. However, for getting products we have to call an API with respect to the category and load those products into the category item as a horizontal `recyclerview`. It all works well.

I should only call the products API when the user scrolls to that particular category. When the user scrolls to a particular category I need to call the products list API and show inside the category item.

My problem is I could not identify the currently visible item in the `recyclerview` and could not find the visible item when scrolling.

Comment: you can add scrollListener and get currentScrollPosition in there from recyclerview and than check for it

Comment: The question is little un clear to me... Specially the second paragraph..

Comment: in your **BindViewHolder** method put a check for the special category and when that special category got called, pass it to your activity via interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@BindView(R.id.general_layout)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

to scroll last:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```

in adapter class:

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }

// convenience method for getting data at click position
    private YourItemType getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onScrolledListener and get the last visible item from the layout manager.
Once the last visible item reaches your widget's index, make an API call.

```
   recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        int lastVisibleItemIndex = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findLastVisibleItemPosition();
         //When the position reaches the element or the one 

         }

    });
```

Comment: onScrolled called only once on first load..then its not getting called while scrolling

Comment: that shouldn't happen. Can you include your layout file?

Comment: It is inside a scrollview. that's why it happens..It is a home page layout.I placed it like a parent scrollview.then a Linearlayout with vertical orientation.inside it a sliderview for showing sliders and then our recyclerview. How do i modify it.? if i remove scrollview , the slider willnot get moved up when scrolling..Please help me out?